# How do I remove the vertical scroll bar that is floating by itself in an html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqwidget

I am attempting to use the code found at `http://www.jqwidgets.com/display-a-grid-in-a-dropdown/` to create a multi column select list. The list is created, however on initial load of the document there is a floating vertical scroll bar near the top of the document as seen in this image:

[image: Floating Scroll Bar]

Once the list is opened, then the bar is displayed where it needs to be. And when an item is selected, the bar disappears.
My code is as follows:

```js
// Start Multicolume
function generatedata(rowscount) {
  // prepare the data
  var data = new Array();
  if (rowscount == undefined) rowscount = 100;
  var firstNames = ["Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"];
  var lastNames = ["Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"];
  var productNames = ["Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Caramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"];
  var priceValues = ["2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"];
  for (var i = 0; i < rowscount; i++) {
    var row = {};
    var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
    var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
    var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    row["id"] = i;
    row["available"] = productindex % 2 == 0;
    row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
    row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
    row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
    row["price"] = price;
    row["quantity"] = quantity;
    data[i] = row;
  }
  return data;
}
var data = generatedata(100);
var source = {
  localdata: data,
  datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
$("#jqxdropdownbutton").jqxDropDownButton({
  width: 150,
  height: 25
});
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
  width: 550,
  source: dataAdapter,
  columns: [{
    text: 'First Name',
    columntype: 'textbox',
    datafield: 'firstname',
    width: 90
  }, {
    text: 'Last Name',
    datafield: 'lastname',
    columntype: 'textbox',
    width: 90
  }, {
    text: 'Product',
    columntype: 'dropdownlist',
    datafield: 'productname',
    width: 180
  }, {
    text: 'Quantity',
    datafield: 'quantity',
    width: 70,
    cellsalign: 'right'
  }, {
    text: 'Price',
    datafield: 'price',
    cellsalign: 'right',
    cellsformat: 'c2'
  }]
});
$("#jqxgrid").bind('rowselect', function(event) {
  var args = event.args;
  var row = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
  var dropDownContent = '<div style="position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 5px;">' + row['firstname'] + ' ' + row['lastname'] + '</div>';
  $("#jqxdropdownbutton").jqxDropDownButton('setContent', dropDownContent);
});
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);
// End Multicolume
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="~/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script>

  <div id="jqxdropdownbutton">
    <div style="border: none;" id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What parameter(s) do I need to enable in order to not see that scrollbar on load?

Comment: Chrome, Win 7 Ent x64

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

I am using the following code now:

```js
  // Start Multicolume
  // prepare the data
 var data = new Array();
 var firstNames = ["Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"];
 var lastNames = ["Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"];
 var productNames = ["Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"];
 var priceValues = ["2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"];
 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   var row = {};
   var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
   var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
   var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
   row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
   row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
   row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
   row["price"] = price;
   row["quantity"] = quantity;
   row["total"] = price * quantity;
   data[i] = row;
 }
 var source = {
   localdata: data,
   datatype: "array"
 };
 $("#jqxdropdownbutton").jqxDropDownButton({
   width: 150,
   height: 25
 });
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
   width: 500,
   source: source,
   theme: 'energyblue',
   columns: [{
     text: 'First Name',
     datafield: 'firstname',
     width: 100
   }, {
     text: 'Last Name',
     datafield: 'lastname',
     width: 100
   }, {
     text: 'Product',
     datafield: 'productname',
     width: 180
   }, {
     text: 'Quantity',
     datafield: 'quantity',
     width: 80,
     cellsalign: 'right'
   }, {
     text: 'Unit Price',
     datafield: 'price',
     width: 90,
     cellsalign: 'right',
     cellsformat: 'c2'
   }, {
     text: 'Total',
     datafield: 'total',
     width: 100,
     cellsalign: 'right',
     cellsformat: 'c2'
   }]
 });

 $("#jqxgrid").bind('rowselect', function(event) {
   var args = event.args;
   var row = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
   var dropDownContent = '<div style="position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 5px;">' + row['firstname'] + ' ' + row['lastname'] + '</div>';
   $("#jqxdropdownbutton").jqxDropDownButton('setContent', dropDownContent);
 });
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);
  // End Multicolume
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownbutton.js"></script>

<div id="jqxdropdownbutton">
  <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```